# When to use native React.useReducer Hook and how it differentiate from Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

So, Hooks are available from React 16.8. From their documentation, Hooks come as a replacer of state in functional components. The basic hooks are: `useState`, `useEffect`, `useContext`, but there are also some additional hooks, one of them being `useReducer`, and it looks like it uses the same `action-dispatch` architecture as Redux does.

The questions would be if it comes as a replacement of Redux because of the resemblance ?

Does it suits particular projects better ?

Where would it fit ?

Comment: Redux and useReducer is still global vs local state. The obvious difference of useReducer is that it doesn't involve middlewares. If you need the functionality of Redux from useReducer, you will soon end up actually writing it from the ground up.

Comment: Perhaps this article sheds some light into this topic: https://www.robinwieruch.de/redux-vs-usereducer/

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Redux is a library that encourages data flow in a specific manner.

`react-redux` on the other hand implements the React friendly approach and provides a lot middlewares and wrappers so that the library consumers do not have to set up the entire process on their own.

While `useReducer` is a part of how Redux works, it isn't Redux in its entirety. In order for you to use dispatch and state deep down in your components you would still have to use `useContext` and `useReducer` in a combination which would be like re-inventing the wheel.

On top of that `useReducer` just gives you a `dispatch` method which you can use to dispatch plain old objects as actions. There is no way yet to add `middlewares` to these such as `thunk`, `saga` and many more.

You also can have multiple reducers in your application using `useReducer` but then the way to combine these to form a single store still have to be managed by the developer.

Also [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) state that `useReducer` is an alternative to `useState` when state logic is complex

> `useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex
>   state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
>   depends on the previous one. `useReducer` also lets you optimize
>   performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can
>   pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.

What hooks like `useContext`, `useReducer` do is that they eliminate the dependency on `Redux` for small apps.

Comment: "On top of that `useReducer` just gives you a `dispatch` method which you can use to dispatch plain old objects as actions. There is no way yet to add `middlewares` to these such as `thunk`, `saga` and many more." - Thank you for this

Comment: Any good use case for `useReducer`? At first glance, it looks a bit over the top for just a local state.

Answer (score 24):

So, if Redux and useReducer were to be compared

Redux:

- centralised state
- forges more de-coupling
- has middlewares: Redux thunk and Redux logger
- actions can only hit one Store
- maybe more suitable for big projects

useReducer:

- local state
- no wrapper component
- needs useContext in order to reinvent the wheel
- comes with other native hooks
- no extra dependencies needed
- multiple stores maybe(actually reducers that can act as store)
- maybe more suitable for small projects

Answer (score 24):

> 1.) Does `useReducer` come as a replacement of Redux?

Let's clarify what Redux is, so we can compare its main parts to a vanilla React solution with `useReducer`:

[image]
(inspired by [this article](https://itnext.io/life-after-redux-21f33b7f189e))

### How to replace all parts with vanilla React

#### Action Dispatcher / State Selector

This is a replacement for what React Redux does:

```
import { useReducer, useContext, useMemo } from "react"
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers"

const GlobalContext = React.createContext()

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(rootReducer, { count: 0 });
  const store = useMemo(() => [state, dispatch], [state]);

  // You can also separate dispatch and state context providers
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Provider is placed at top-level to emulate a global state store
ReactDOM.render(<Provider> <App /> </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'))

const Comp = () => {
  // extract this UI logic in its own custom hook for better encapsulation
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalContext);
  // ...
};
```

#### Data Store

Redux store can be instantiated ([`createStore`](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore)) and accessed quite flexibly. With vanilla React, the store is bound to a single `useReducer` in the UI. We can pass its state down via context or props.

#### Store Reducer

The exact same pure `rootReducer` function is used for vanilla as with Redux.

#### Middleware API

`redux-thunk` and `redux-saga` are two of the most popular [middlewares](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) for async operations and side effects in Redux. With `useReducer`, we do *not* have any built-in middleware API. Instead we do the async processing first and afterwards forward the result to `dispatch`:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalContext);
// ...
<button onClick={() => dispatchAsync(dispatch)}> Process </button>

const dispatchAsync = dispatch => {
  fetchData().then(data => dispatch({type: "increment"}, data)) 
};
```

It is still possible to integrate existing Redux middlewares with `useReducer`, as long as their [common API](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#arguments) is covered - you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146795/react-usereducer-async-data-fetch/61923286#61923286) for more infos.

#### Redux DevTools (Time traveling, debug support)

There is no *direct* integration for `useReducer` available, so you may miss an important workflow tool here. The [reinspect](https://github.com/troch/reinspect) library uses [Redux DevTools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools) to also inspect `useState` and `useReducer` (haven't tested though).

---

> 2.) Does it suits particular projects better? Where would it fit?

`useReducer` usage starts with local state and in the component scope. As you have seen, it can also be lifted to the global scope to take over most of Redux' roles.

In some situations, `useReducer` can even provide more flexibility, as the global state can be divided between multiple contexts. Example: Separate low priority and high priority state changes in different state trees/contexts.

With vanilla React, you will mainly miss out on Redux DevTools and popular middleware libraries. On the other hand functions like [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) can be easily re-implemented for `useReducer`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57298115/5669456).

General rule of thumb: *Start* using vanilla React for your app and add functionality like a global Redux store incrementally, [as soon as you feel](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367), this becomes mandatory (also depends on app size).

---

```js
const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(rootReducer, { count: 0 });
  const store = useMemo(() => [state, dispatch], [state]);

  // You can also separate dispatch and state context providers
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

const rootReducer = (state, action) =>
  action === "increment" ? { count: state.count + 1 } : state;

const dispatchAsync = dispatch => {
  // just do the async operation before and invoke dispatch afterwards
  setTimeout(() => dispatch("increment"), 1000);
};

const Comp = () => {
  // You can extract this UI logic in its own custom hook for better encapsulation
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Counter: {state.count}</div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatchAsync(dispatch)}>
        Increment async (1sec delay)
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Provider><Comp /></Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-32Gmw5rBDXyMjg/73FgpukoTZdMrxuYW7tj8adbN8z4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-bjQ42ac3EN0GqK40pC9gGi/YixvKyZ24qMP/9HiGW7w=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>var { useReducer, useContext, useMemo } = React</script>
```

Comment: Context will re render all child components, isn't that a problem? Redux do not re-render child components.

Comment: @mestarted in above code snippet, we have a stable `children` reference inside `Provider`, so it never gets re-rendered on context value changes (also assuming, that `Provider` is put at the top/root of your component hierarchy for no/rare updates). Though you are right, [performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#react-redux-and-rendering-behavior) is one factor in larger apps, that should be carefully evaluated between these concepts.

Answer (score 15):

`useReducer`'s state is local to a single component - if you wanted to use this state throughout your app, you'd need to pass it (and/or the `dispatch` function) down via the props. It's effectively just a more structured version of `useState` - in fact, [`useState` is implemented using `useReducer` under the hood](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/2b93d686e359c7afa299e2ec5cf63160a32a1155/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L782)!

Redux, on the other hand, does a bit more - among other things, it makes the state available to the entire app via a Context, and then provides APIs to connect your deeply nested components to this state without passing props down.

So in other words:

- `useReducer` gives you structured *local* state updates.
- Redux gives you structured *and centralized* state updates.

If you wanted to 'roll your own Redux' with Hooks, you'd need to use some combination of `useReducer` and `useContext`.